# How Do I get values from the previous form fields?

Tags: forms, grails, groovy, grails-controller

I have two forms, notably for classes named `User` and `Company`. In the `User` form, when the user finds that his/her own company is not already in DB, then he/she will create a new `Company`. I have changed the `save` action of the `Company` controller to something like this :

```
def save() { 
        def companyInstance = new Company(params)
        if (!companyInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [companyInstance: companyInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'company.label', default: 'Company'), companyInstance.id])
        redirect(controller:"user", action:"create")
    }
```

That is after saving the new company, I'm redirecting to `User`'s `create` action. However it works quite well, the user who have already entered some value (i.e before going to the `Company`'s `create` action) are been missing in the `User` form  fields.

How do I retrieve the values back on the `User` field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Webflows](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC2/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow%20Webflows). Webflow is a list of forms, one after another that keep state between them. This way you can go 'back' to User form later without loosing entered values. Webflows are not easy - it's for semi-advanced users.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist your user before making the company, you would make a hidden field with the user ID on your company form. If you wish to postpone creating the user until all data is collected, you would store all the user information on the company form.

Otherwise you would have to do like Tomasz suggested, using Webflows